# How I do get the data from a body request into my interface?

Tags: typescript, express, oop, interface

I have this IFoo interface.

```
interface IFoo{

    id: string | null;
    name: string | null;
    year: number | null;
}
```

but the data from the request body has other properties than my interface:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "year": 2015,
        "title": "Hello World"
    }
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
let { properties } = req.body;
let data = properties as IFoo;
console.log(data);
```

This code prints all properties when I only want 'year' property.

```
{ "year": 2013, "title": "titulo" }
```

I would like a way to discard other properties. Is it possible?

Comment: ...`data.year`? Note that TypeScript *only exists at compile time*, so it can't and won't do any runtime processing.

Comment: data.year works, but the interface has more properties so I would prefer to discard unmatch fields

Comment: Then you'll need to do so explicitly at runtime, typescript can't do that for you.